# How to make NSAttributedString centred align when converting it from HTML string?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

**HTML text:**

```
<span style="color: rgb(158, 29, 255);"><b>This</b> is a <i>simple</i> <u>text</u>.</span>
```

---

**Output:**

**This** is a *simple* 
text.

---

**And this is my code to convert HTML text to an attributed string:**

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
initWithData:[@"<span style="color: rgb(158, 29, 255);"><b>This</b> is a <i>simple</i> <u>text</u>.</span>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
 options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle} 
documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

However, it's not setting attributed string to centered alignment. What's wrong?

Comment: You can't use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` with `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:`. Add it after.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:):

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data
                     options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                      id> *)options
          documentAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                      id> * _Nullable *)dict
                       error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

> **options**
>   Document attributes for interpreting the document contents. **NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute**, **NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute**, and **NSDefaultAttributesDocumentAttribute** are supported option keys. If not specified, the method examines the data to attempt to determine the appropriate attributes.

`NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` is not a supported option key and it is ignored.

However, you can try appending `<center>` to the HTML as the following:

```
"<center><span style=\"color: rgb(158, 29, 255);\"><b>This</b> is a <i>simple</i> <u>text</u>.</span></center>"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

1) Take **UIWebView** and **UITextView**.

2) Set your Attributed string in **WebView**.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[yourAttributedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```

3) Get your **HTML** string from **UIWebView**.

```
NSString *simpleHtmlString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```